# GSI with DynamoDB.DocumentElement and Node.JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, aws-sdk-nodejs

I've got a question regarding GSI. The question is quite easy for people who are working with DynamoDB :)

Currently, I'm learning about AWS/DynamoDB with creating a blog. So each post got one category. I got one big problem that if I want to get all posts which got a special category. Now I'm using a scan and contains a filter.

EDIT:
To create models I'm using 'dynamodb-toolbox'

I heard that I can apply a GSI and get all posts with category by searching with GSI. The biggest problem is... I do not know how can I create GSI, how can I use it in query width DocumentClient and node.js

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How does your DynamoDB data model currently look like?

Comment: `
    schema: {
        pk: { type: 'string', alias: 'type', default: 'POST' },
        sk: { type: 'string', alias: 'id' },
        title: { type: 'string' },
        category: { type: 'string' },
        description: { type: 'string'},
    }
`
this is model from dynamo-toolbox, so each post got these fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not know how can I create GSI

This is [on the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html), more specifically available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/getting-started-step-6.html).

> I got one big problem that if I want to get all posts which got a special category. Now I'm using a scan and contains a filter.

In this case and based on your data model currently, you need to configure a GSI with `category` being the partition key and `id` being the sort key, where you need to configure the primary key as being the composite primary key of PK and SK, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey).

This will allow you to [query the data by category on that GSI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.Querying), as you have the category as the partition key, you will hit one partition when you perform your query.

> how can I use it in query width DocumentClient and node.js

I suggest that you figure these out first, and make it work in isolation w/o worrying about your programming language constraints. Once you get a handle of this, you can worry about programming language challenges in isolation.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help! That was really helpful for me. All I want to ask is - is it possible to create this index via code? Or should I go directly to DynamoDB table in AWS-CLI and create it on my own?

Comment: "is it possible to create this index via code": you can, anything you can do in AWS console, that you can pretty much do in your own code, through AWS CLI and your infra as code tooling (e.g. terraform). GSI creation is something you need to do once per your need. So, I would take it out of the application, and run it somewhere else.